# Get security details of remote file

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to get the security details of a remote file x ( its dacl, sacl, owner ) . I tried GetNamedSecurityInfo , but it works only for local files or files that the current user has access on. I  do have an user credential that can access x. How can i impersonate this credentials and access the remote file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`LogonUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx) function together with the [`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to impersonate the current thread using the domain user credentials.